# Laravel: checking id in controller to be certain instance

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel application with the following route:

```
Route::get('event/{id}/stages', [
            'as' => 'events_list',
            'uses' => 'EventsController@show'
]);
```

In the controller I define the method show as follows:

```
 public function show($id) {
        $event = Event::find($id);
        return view('showEvent', ['event' => $event]);
  }
```

The issue is that I can pass whatever value in {id}, so it should work for

- http://localhost:5000/event/1/stages

but it should not work for

- http://localhost:5000/event/20/stages
- http://localhost:5000/event/foo/stages

The first one should not work because 20 is not a valid id (there are only 4 events) and foo should not work because it's a string. Both should be checked and redirected to a 404 page.

Ideally I can just check if the {id} is an Event instance that has an entry in the database.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may constrain the format of your route parameters using the where method on a route instance.

```
Route::get('event/{id}/stages', [
            'as' => 'events_list',
            'uses' => 'EventsController@show'
])->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

To check if the Event exists, you can use route model binding :

```
Route::get('event/{event}/stages', [
            'as' => 'events_list',
            'uses' => 'EventsController@show'
]);
```

Then:

```
public function show(Event $event) {
    return view('showEvent', ['event' => $event]);
}
```

If a matching model instance is not found in the database, a 404 HTTP response will be automatically generated.

Comment: I like this idea of route model binding. However, in my route, I can use {event} or {events} and I don't understand why really. Do I need to add something in the RouteServiceProvider file?

Comment: You don't need that. Laravel will automatically resolve type-hinted Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose variable names match a route segment name.

Comment: Thanks. And how would it work when I need to apply a 'where' clause. Normally I would do $events = Event::where('category_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

Comment: Constrain the format of your route parameters, and perform the query in your controller method.

Comment: OK, so I will do this: $events = Event::where('category_id', $event->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findOrFail()` instead of `find()`.

```
public function show($id) {
    $event = Event::findOrFail($id);
    if ($event->isEmpty()) {
        abort(404);
    }
    return view('showEvent', ['event' => $event]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Thought about that as well. However the isEmpty() is not working for me. Instead I'm using if (! $event) {about(404); }